# Tailwind on firefox: w-1/2 works others like w-1/3, w-3/4 don't dispite being in the css generated file

Tags: css, typescript, firefox, tailwind-css, browser-support

I am building an app using tailwind, symfony with encore, react, typescript.

Some classes don't seems to be recognised by firefox but works with safari.

[image: screen capt w-1/2]
[image: screen capt w-3/4]

`postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./templates/**/*.html.twig",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js",
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './assets/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    'node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

sample of the dist css

[image]
[image]

firefox version 109.0.1

Comment: You haven't shown that a `.w-3/4` rule is in your CSS.

Comment: i added the screencapture now

Comment: Caching, refreshing? All this causes issues.